# Load image in C to unsigned char

Tags: c++, c, image, image-processing, cuda

I have problem to make a small program to convert to gray scale. I have to load BMP file to unsigned char and send this to CUDA function (I've found this: http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Image-Processing-with-CUDA-650.php).

I've used CImg, but it can't save values as unsigned char and send to CUDA function (return values is not a gray scale image).
How can I load image to unsigned char as

`px[0] = R , px[1] = G, px[2] = B, px[3] = A` and so on.

Maybe I'm testing on too small image? (10 x 10 px).

Comment: Open the file in gimp, save as [binary PGM format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html).  Then all you need to do when reading it is find the end of the header.

Comment: @pQB Kinda is.  Seems like the entire problem revolves around CUDA - I was about to add the tag back in.  Then again, I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what the question is myself :)

Comment: Is your problem in the part of loading an image from file? If so, then all you need is a library.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan The question is related to How to load image to unsigned char. Maybe I was wrong but there is not a doubt about CUDA. The problem seems to be How to convert from RGB to GrayScale. Said that, if the problem is about the CPU-GPU memory transfers or the logic with in the kernel, It should be added to the question.

Comment: CImg member functions return image pixels as a T structure consisting of unsigned ints. What cuda function are you trying to call?

Comment: Yeah, the question is vague enough that I'm not too worried.  I'm moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to load the image file into memory

If it is a bmp, there is a very simple [bitmap loading lib](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/). Then once you have it as a unsigned char[] array on the CPU you can use any of the CUDA functions to copy it to the GPU and work on it.

The [opencv image processing](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV%20GPU%20FAQ) lib now supports CUDA very well, and its GPU image format is a very good place to start writing your own image processing tasks in CUDA.

And of course it has all the load/save/display functionality you could want.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I wrote [cuda-grayscale](http://code.google.com/p/cuda-grayscale/), which is a demo application that shows how to integrate [OpenCV](http://code.opencv.org/projects/OpenCV/wiki/WikiStart) and CUDA: it loads an image from the disk using [OpenCV](http://code.opencv.org/projects/OpenCV/wiki/WikiStart) and converts it to grayscale using CUDA.

You can download it and take a look at the code on the [project page](http://code.google.com/p/cuda-grayscale/). Basically, I create a new `float` array to store the original `unsigned char` data and send it to the GPU for processing.